# How do I "rasterize"/finalize a grid repeat in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, grids

I've created this brick pattern in Adobe Illustrator using Object > Repeat > Grid.

[image: The brick pattern I created in Adobe Illustrator]

I want to tell Illustrator that I'm done using the grid/repeat tool, and that I'd like to be able to edit each brick as if I had created them by hand.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The term is expand.

Comment: Is this new functionality?  The version of Illustrator CC I'm using doesn't have Object > Repeat > Grid.   Did you mean Object > Pattern > Make,  then Tile Type:  "Grid"?  After making a pattern you click Done. To expand/bake in a pattern filled object, click Object > Expand.  To rasterize an object, click Object > Rasterize.

Comment: @BillyKerr idk, i'm using [Illustrator 26.5](https://i.imgur.com/n7UoqJa.png). You can see the grid feature [here](https://i.imgur.com/GlLwctp.png).

Comment: @joojaa thank you!

Comment: @MEATTAIL - yeah must be new.  Don't see the point of it TBH. Illustrator already had tiled pattern functionality. I'm not upgrading just to find out. Sorry.  Yeah, try "Expand".

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments: Select the Grid Repeat object, and then choose **Expand** from the **Object** menu. Next from the same menu you may want to select **Clipping Mask > Release.** Finally, either use the Direct Selection tool (white arrow) or **Ungroup** the bricks to edit them individually.